# Unable to get my Android XML file to Inflate via fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-fragments, android-inflate

Good day StackOverflowians, I have question about an Android App I am working on. I am using the tutorial from the guide at this link here: http://www.jamesfroggatt.com/2014/04/892/
While the fragments themselves are visible, I cannot seem to get the xml to inflate correctly. Currently, this is what my app screen looks like:
[image]

The problem is, my xml file housing the Autos fragment actually reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- fragment_autos -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/autos_updated_as_of"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button and whatnot" />



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/autos_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Words!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

So something SHOULD be showing on the autos tab, right? Finally, here is my Java code (most of it is copied from said previously mentioned tutorial with some cut out to decrease clutter of code)

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class NewMainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAB_KEY_INDEX = "tab_key";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ActionBar
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // create new tabs and set up the titles of the tabs
        ActionBar.Tab mAutoTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Autos");
        ActionBar.Tab mEarningsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Earnings");


        // create the fragments
        Fragment mAutosFragment = new AutosFragment();
        Fragment mEarningsFragment = new EarningsFragment();

        // bind the fragments to the tabs - set up tabListeners for each tab
        mAutoTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mAutosFragment, getApplicationContext()));
        mEarningsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mEarningsFragment, getApplicationContext()));

        // add the tabs to the action bar
        actionbar.addTab(mAutoTab);
        actionbar.addTab(mEarningsTab);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "tab is " + savedInstanceState.getInt(TAB_KEY_INDEX, 0),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(
                    TAB_KEY_INDEX, 0));
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.tabs_menu, menu);
                return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menuitem_search:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;

                }
                return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "onSaveInstanceState: tab is"
                        + getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        outState.putInt(TAB_KEY_INDEX, getActionBar()
                .getSelectedNavigationIndex());

    }


    class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        public Fragment fragment;
        public Context context;

        public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment, Context context) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
            this.context = context;

        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

-And the AutosFragment Java File-

```
//Handles the Autos Fragment of the tabs from the main menu
public class AutosFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_autos, container, false);
    }

}
```

Anyone have any ideas why the xml is not inflating properly with the buttons, textviews, and lists? I am a bit lost!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of this:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "tab is " + savedInstanceState.getInt(TAB_KEY_INDEX, 0),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(
                TAB_KEY_INDEX, 0));
    }
```

Also, since you have you buttons and textviews in the fragment_auto layout, try changing this to(in addition):

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_auto);
```